# JavaMelody - access statistic only for allowed address IP

Tags: java, java-melody

I am using the [`JavaMelody library`](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody) and I would like to restrict access to the context / monitoring.

Currently, I have added an entry in `web.xml`:

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>allowed-addr-pattern</param-name>
    <param-value>(first_ip)|(second_ip)</param-value>
</init-param>
```

But when I call up the resource / monitoring, it receives `"Forbidden access"`

Is it possible to restrict access only for specific `IP addresses`?

Answer (score 0):

The IP address of your computer, as seen by the server, does not match the regexp in `allowed-addr-pattern`.

So either you have miswritten the regexp in `allowed-addr-pattern` or you have something like a Apache http proxy which is masking the IP addresses seen by your server.

You may want to use the `authorized-users` parameter to have basic authentication instead of using `allowed-addr-pattern`.